# can´t compiling flutter Geolocator using LInux Mint #882

Tags: android, linux, flutter, geolocation, linux-mint

My project is a simple app to print longitude and latitude

I´m using:
Linux Mint 19.3

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'

compileSdkVersion 31

and the results of the compilation is show below:

---

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Failed to transform play-services-base-17.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /home/luis/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/bb3cc3ced1388fcd9c0c925717b75148/jetified-play-services-base-17.0.0.
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.3-6503028-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error during compile '/home/luis/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/bb3cc3ced1388fcd9c0c925717b75148/jetified-play-services-base-17.0.0/res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
```

Answer (score 0):

How about minSDKVersion ?
try with:
compileSdkVersion 31
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 29
and geolocator: ^7.6.0

Comment: nothing changes. The results were exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

It's related to your local cache.
There are two ways to solve this.

1. Try **fluter pub cache repair**.
2. Open Your Project ProjectName/android project in android studio and syn Gradle. And build it through the android studio.

Comment: I made your suggestion and the results were the same.

Comment: /home/luis/.gradle
Delete .gradle folder on above  path. 
run   flutter clean , 
 flutter pub get

Comment: .gradle deleted... flutter clean, get and nothing again...same results

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I figured out to fix this problem at the android/build.gradle

downgraded 4.1.0 to 3.4.2. Why? because I have another app using this version.

```
dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```